# ToLookup(): access groups/items by numeric index?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following product list

```
public sealed class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}: {1} - {2}]", Id, Category, Value);  
    }
}

var products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Id = 1, Category = "Electronics", Value = 15.0 },
    new Product { Id = 2, Category = "Groceries", Value = 40.0 },
    new Product { Id = 3, Category = "Garden", Value = 210.3 },
    new Product { Id = 4, Category = "Pets", Value = 2.1 },
    new Product { Id = 5, Category = "Electronics", Value = 19.95 },
    new Product { Id = 6, Category = "Pets", Value = 5.50 },
    new Product { Id = 7, Category = "Electronics", Value = 250.0 },
};
```

You can use `ToLookup()` to find the values in the list easily.

```
// create lookup
var productLookup = products.ToLookup(p => p.Category);
```

Now I want to get some information out of it:

```
// get the number of categories/groups
Console.WriteLine(productLookup.Count());
// FAILS: get the number of items in the second category
Console.WriteLine(productLookup[2].Count());
// FAILS: get a certain item by numeric index (1: group | 3: item in group)
Console.WriteLine(productLookup[1][3]);
```

I have to work with a numeric index and can't use the *Category* string, except I would create another structure holding all the keys.

Is a `GroupBy()` together with `ToDictionary()` the better choice or how can I do that with `ToLookup()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any reason that you don't just do this:

```
var productLookup = products.ToLookup(p => p.Category).Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

The type of `productLookup` is now just `Product[][]`.

Then your code runs just fine (once you use valid array index values):

```
Console.WriteLine(productLookup.Count());
Console.WriteLine(productLookup[2].Count());
Console.WriteLine(productLookup[0][2]);
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Comment: Note that once you have arrays, you're better off using `Length`

Comment: @Aravol - No, not really. Because arrays implement `ICollection<T>` it just calls `.Count` without iterating the elements.

Comment: Interesting, so it is confirmed on the Reference Source. Note that arrays implement `ICollection` rather than `ICollection<T>`, but the end result is the same when calling `Count()`

Comment: @Aravol - Yes, I checked on the source. Also arrays do implement `ICollection<T>`. Here's the full list for an `int` array - `ICloneable`, `ICollection`, `ICollection<Int32>`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<Int32>`, `IList`, `IList<Int32>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<Int32>`, `IReadOnlyList<Int32>`, `IStructuralComparable`, `IStructuralEquatable`.

Answer (score 2):

`ILookup` doesn't have an indexer to get the element according to the index, but it has one to get sequence of values indexed by a specified key, in your case category.

```
public interface ILookup<TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>, IEnumerable
{
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> sequence of values indexed
    //     by a specified key.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   key:
    //     The key of the desired sequence of values.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> sequence of values indexed
    //     by the specified key.
    IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] { get; }
}
```

But to solve your issue you can use the [`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var count=productLookup.ElementAt(2).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ILookup<TKey, TElement>` produced by the `ToLookup` method is a dictionary data structure, and as such it is intended to be used for effectively searching by a key. It does not naturaly provide indexed access (the same applies to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`). Of course, since `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` and `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is `IEnumerable<TElement>`, you can use [Enumerable.ElementAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx) to simulate indexed access like this

```
Console.WriteLine(productLookup.ElementAt(2).Count());
Console.WriteLine(productLookup.ElementAt(1).ElementAt(3));
```

but that's not natural.

If all you need is indexed access, then the following could be more appropriate:

```
var productList = products.GroupBy(p => p.Category)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Elements = g.ToList() })
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(productList.Count);
Console.WriteLine(productList[2].Elements.Count);
Console.WriteLine(productList[1].Elements[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ToList or ToArray. It gives you an Index

`Console.WriteLine(  productLookup.ToList()[2].Count() )`;